# Punycode domains doesn't work with requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, punycode

Is there an easy way to fetch punycode domains? I tried using the requests module, but it didn't work.

The following code doesn't work:

```py
import requests
requests.get("https://.la")
```

```py
InvalidURL: Failed to parse: https://.la
```

using `Python 3.10.4`, `requests==2.28.1`, `urllib3==1.26.13`

Comment: I tested it with a domain I have that contains é, and that worked. The issue is related to the emoji, which is basically not legal in IDNs. Emoji are symbols, which were excluded from IDNs about a decade ago (phishers were using symbols too well). See RFC 5892 pages 5-10 or [the github issue for the code you're using](https://github.com/kjd/idna/issues/18).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using the following function

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse


def convert_idna_address(url: str) -> str:
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    return urlunparse(
        parsed_url._replace(netloc=parsed_url.netloc.encode("idna").decode("ascii"))
    )
```